# See who granted a role in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want a query which tells me which user granted a role to another user in my Postgres database. Expected output would be as follows:

```
SELECT  role, grantor, grantee, grant_date FROM information_schema.<table>;

role              grantor              grantee            grant_date
grp_db_admin      Tom Dwan             Eli Elezra         2019-09-09
........
grp_db_viewer     Viktor Blom          Patrick Antonius   2019-08-02
```

So far I've found the `information_schema.role_table_grants` and `pg_catalog.pg_roles` tables, however these don't allow me to see who it was that granted someone a role group.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't register the timestamp when a privilege was granted. The semantics would be unclear: what should the time be when you restore a dump? The time the privilege was originally granted or the time of the restore?

Anyway, you can get the rest of the information from the system catalogs:

```
SELECT roleid::regrole, member::regrole, grantor::regrole
FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members;
```

Comment: Perfect that's what I was looking for! No worries about the timestamp, I'm planning to record this information each day so will just default to NOW(). Thanks for the help!